# add html to an image file

Tags: html, image

I want to be able to add html links to image files, jpeg, gif, png, bmp, etc.

I've seen image maps are old and you could add more than one html link to the image, but I can't see a way of doing it so that if I upload an image to my social media (for example) all I am doing is uploading an image, say it's called selfie.jpg.

The selfie.jpg file's metadata contains the html links within it, kind of like steganography hides messages within the data, except I don't need it to be encrypted or anything, it's just so I can post an image with more than one html link to nay social media account and all the links work, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: With SVG images you can embed links

Comment: You could use https://www.image-maps.com/ to generate an image map. Build a landing page in html/css and then link to your landing page of the image from your social media account.

Answer (score 0):

None of the formats you list provide any mechanism for embedding hyperlinks.

If you want to provide any kind of not-completely-trivial document, then use a hosting service designed for that type of content.